# CSS - Rotating a Background Image

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

I have a CSS style that uses a background image (code: `background-image: url("folderimage.jpg");`). Is there a way using jQuery/CSS to rotate between multiple CSS Background Images? (Please provide an example).

Comment: what do u mean by rotate. Do you want to change them in some time period?

Comment: @sushilbharwani - Yes. I would use images 1-5 and have then rotate.

Comment: @Blender - I have used few different plug-ins that use regular images not background-image in the css. I am needing to change the background-image photo because of how another program I am using outputs the image. Have I tried anything yet? No because I am not sure what will work and where to start

Comment: @Lynda I don't know why the power users are always so hostile.  Obviously you don't know where to start which is why you're asking.

Comment: @Jack - I agree but with a forum the size of SO you will see that. It is okay though =>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rotate background-image in css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46783959/how-to-rotate-background-image-in-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something of this sort would work. I haven't tested the code, but the idea is to have an array of five images and change them after a timeout. I can explain the code if you need.

```javascript
var theImages = new Array(); 

theImages[0] = '1.gif'
theImages[1] = '2.gif'
theImages[2] = '3.gif'
theImages[3] = '4.gif'
theImages[4] = '5.gif'

function changeBGImage(){
  var whichImage = Math.round(Math.random()*(p-1));
  jQuery('#elementHavingProperty').css('background-image','url('+theImages[whichImage+'])');
} 

movement = setTimeout("changeBGImage()",1000000);
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe of topic. But you can checkout my code for how I rotate all contents on a page.

[My web page](http://gustavstromberg.se/sandbox/html5/rotating/)

Comment: The link is a 404.