# How to rotate background-image in css?

Tags: html, css

I have a background image with a style called north:

```
.north {
    background-image: url("./images/turtle-north.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50px 50px;
}
```

This is part of a reactjs component that renders a grid. The image displays fine with this rule. However when I try to rotate it with this rule:

```
.rotate_ninety {
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(150px);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(150px);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(150px);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(150px);
    transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(150px);
}
```

The img is pushed down ie not at the top left position in the grid anymore. How can I rotate the image and keep this position?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*"The img is pushed down ie not at the top left position in the grid anymore"*

It's because you're using `translateX`, if you want just to rotate the image, don't move it, use only `transform: rotate`:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.rotate_ninety {
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/angular/pic_angular.jpg" class="rotate_ninety">
```

Comment: this rotates the whole block, not just the background image.